# How to add dynamic values to the <mat-label> in angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to display a read only review page in Angular 9 with all the inputs given in a previously completed form. If i want to use mat-label, how to use the ngModel ?

Eg.,

Username : ABC;
Email Id : abc@abc.com

"ABC" and "abc@abc.com" should be fetched from the previously filled form. How can I achieve this? Thanks is advance!

Comment: add the code you tried and try creating a sample demo, check out [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can also show inputs in disabled previously filled control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I recommend you to do is to use the two way binding for your inputs as they are only read only.

Eg

The first step:

.ts

```
private email:string;
```

.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="email"/>
```

Second readonly step. If they are in the same component just user the variable binding

.html(same .ts)

```
<mat-label>{{email}}</mat-label>
```

If the two pages are not in the same component then you can use services to highlight the variable into a service and then you can access from both components the value of it

Comment: Seems like ngModel is deprecated in angular 7 for the form field.. Is there any other way to handle it ?